# How do I sync two folders using bash so a change in one folder gets reflected in a different folder?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

For example, I have FolderA and FolderB. I'd like any new change in FolderA to be reflected in FolderB whether it's a change in a files name or adding or deleting a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want FolderB to reflect instantaneously any and all changes to FolderA, then the solution is for FolderB to be a soft link to FolderA.

```
ln -s FolderA FolderB
```

If you want FolderB to be periodically updated with a separate copy of the files in FolderA, use `rsync`.  Run the following command periodically:

```
rsync --archive --delete FolderA FolderB
```

#### Example using soft links

Let's create a directory FolderA and put some files in it:

```
$ ls
$ mkdir FolderA
$ touch FolderA/{1..3}.txt
```

Now, let's create FolderB and see what is in it:

```
$ ln -s FolderA FolderB
$ ls FolderB
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

The files in FolderB are the same files that we see in FolderA:

```
$ ls FolderA
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

Note that the `ln` command should be used to *create* FolderB.  If FolderB already exists when the command is run, the results will likely not be what you want.

Comment: My only qualm with this is that this method puts a copy of FolderA in FolderB and then keeps that sync. In other words, now I have a copy of FolderA within FolderB, but I was hoping the inside of FolderB would look like the inside of FolderA. Is there a way to accomplish that component? If not, I can try to make this work

Comment: "I was hoping the inside of FolderB would look like the inside of FolderA"  That is what should happen.  See the example added to the answer.  When you run the `ln -s FolderA FolderB`, it is important that FolderB not already exist.  If it does exist, rename it or delete it first and then try again.  If it doesn't behave like the example in my answer, then I will need more details on what you are doing.

Comment: Got it! That clarifies things. Thank you.